# Failing to implement gravity (or jump mechanism) into a python tkinter game

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make it so when the user hits the up arrow, it jumps up and then falls back down. With the program I have, it seems to go up and down without displaying the positions, so it appears to stay in place. Anyone know why this is happening?

```
if self.direction == 4 and self.y>0: # move up
    self.y = self.y - 6
    self.canvas.coords(self.circle, self.x, self.y, self.x+10, self.y+10)
    self.y = self.y + 6
    self.canvas.coords(self.circle, self.x, self.y, self.x+10, self.y+10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete movement is happening before the screen can redraw.

Add a delay using the `after` function.

```
if self.direction == 4 and self.y>0: # move up
    self.y = self.y - 6
    self.canvas.coords(self.circle, self.x, self.y, self.x+10, self.y+10)
    self.y = self.y + 6
    # wait 1/2 second
    root.after(500, lambda : self.canvas.coords(self.circle, self.x, self.y, self.x+10, self.y+10))
```

For completeness, here is the update suggested by @Oakley. No lambda is required.

`root.after(500, self.canvas.coords, self.circle, self.x, self.y, self.x+10, self.y+10`)

Comment: Great, thank you. Is the 500,  lambda what sets how long the delay is?

Comment: @Will Its in milliseconds, so 1000 is 1000 ms which is 1 second and so on.. and `lambda` is for calling the function, like `after(ms,func)`

Comment: You don't need to use `lambda` here. You can pass arguments to functions called by after: `root.after(500, self.canvas,coords, self.circle, self.x, ...)`